# Trouble installing Xpages Debug Toolbar

Tags: xpages

I am having trouble installing the Xpages Debug Toolbar in my environment.

I was able to install into Designer.

One thing I do not understand is the difference between the two controls:

[image]

I tried to install on the server as well, but could not. I am not really sure how to do it.

I did create an uplatesite.nsf on my server. Then I choose "Import Features" and maneuvered to the jar file in the feature folder of the Xpages Debug folder.

When I tried to import it I got this message:

[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Bryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between the two controls. It's a bug in 9.0.x Designer which means components created from custom controls appear twice. You can select either - they both map to the same component.

The error when installing to the update site has one of two possible causes.

1. A bug with 9.0.1 FP3 which broke use of LS2J. There is a JVM fix that resolves this, or upgrade to 9.0.1 FP4. Both will resolve the error.
2. If you install a plugin to Designer, then try to install into Notes, it throws an error. Close Notes and Designer, restart and run again.

Both causes throw a similar LS2J error. I **think** that particular error message is the second cause, which probably fits in with what you say about installing to Designer and then trying to add to an Update Site.

Comment: Paul, we are running 9.0.1 FP2 on the server I am trying to install the feature on, so it must be number 2. I came in this morning and I got the same error. The update site application is on the server, and I try to install the feature from the folder on my local drive, and I get the error. Should I uninstall it from my designer and then install it on the server?

Comment: The server version doesn't affect the ability to upload to the update site. It's just the client version. If it happened again this morning, it sounds like the client may be FP3.

Comment: Oh I see, yes that is my client version. I will update it and try again. I bet that will fix it.